# Inheritance for custom fields in Shopware 6

Tags: plugins, shopware

Is there a way to create inheritance for custom fields? Something like:

```
(new CustomFields())->addFlag(new Inherited());
```

In my case if I create a custom field for a product then its variants should get inherited values if there is nothing specific assigned to it. But it does not seem to work in the current `6.2.2` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported as of Shopware 6.2.3. Maybe it will be in a future version.